# How to integrate Oracle apex 19.2 to EBS 12.2

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, oracle11gr2

i need to know how to integrate oracle Apex 19 to Ebs 12.2

I have a oracle white pater from oracle 12c and apex 18 installation guide line, but that document was not match form apex 19. I did apex 19 installation part but I have to integrate it into oracle ebs 12.2

please help me to integrate apex 19 to ebs 12.2